# Convert array of string to array of object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an empty array and data. With a function I can put data into my array, this is the function :

```
foreach($values as $key => $value){
  $name = $slugify->slugify($value->getColonne()->getName());

  if(!isset($array[$value->getPosition()])){
       $array[$value->getPosition()] = array();
  }

  array_push($array[$value->getPosition()],  $name . ":" . $value->getValue());
}
```

With this, i have at the end : `[["nom:andraud"], ["nom:andro", "prenom:clement"]]`

But I expected to have something like : `[{nom:"andraud"}, {nom:"andro", "prenom:clement"}]`

I need an array of object, not an array of strings.

Comment: yeah, but not the same

Comment: Your questions tell me you have to learn PHP first. Read a tutorial, browse the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), read the comments and answers you get on your SO questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`stdClass`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting)

By typecasting

```
$object = (object)$array;
```

Or you can create object in `foreach`

```
foreach($values as $key => $value){
    $name = $slugify->slugify($value->getColonne()->getName());

    if(!isset($array[$value->getPosition()])){
        $array[$value->getPosition()] = new stdClass();
    }

    $array[$value->getPosition()]->$name = $value->getValue();
}
```

Comment: Not exactly, if you see my last example, the second object has two elements, it's not two objects in an array but one object with two elements.

Comment: @ClémentAndraud, yeah, I've just edited. And what for `$value->getPosition()`? It's key in array? But why it's not presented in your example?

Comment: Position is the position of the object in the array. In my example the first element has positon 0 and the second and third has 1

Comment: @ClémentAndraud ok, I have recfactored, Try now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so instead of an **array of arrays of strings**, you need an **array of ojects**.

In this case, you need to do something like the following:

```
foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
   $name = $slugify->slugify($value->getColonne()->getName());

   if (!isset($array[$value->getPosition()])) {
       $array[$value->getPosition()] = new stdClass();
   }
   $array[$value->getPosition()]->$name = $value->getValue();
}
```

**NOTE**

In PHP >= 5.3 **strict mode**, if you need to create a property inside an object, without generating an error, instead of:

```
$foo = new StdClass();
$foo->bar = '1234';
```

You need to create the property as a position in an associative array, and then cast the array back to an object. You'd do something like:

```
$foo = array('bar' => '1234');
$foo = (object)$foo;
```

So, in that case your code will need to like like this:

```
foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
   $name = $slugify->slugify($value->getColonne()->getName());

   // cast the object as an array to create the new property,
   // or create a new array if empty
   if (isset($array[$value->getPosition()])) {
       $array[$value->getPosition()] = (array)$array[$value->getPosition()];
   } else {
       $array[$value->getPosition()] = array();
   }
   // create the new position
   $array[$value->getPosition()][$name] = $value->getValue();

   // now simply cast the array back into an object :)
   $array[$value->getPosition()] = (object)$array[$value->getPosition()];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not this at all ;)

Comment: `$array[$value->getPosition()] = new stdClass();` would create new object every iteration of `$value->getPosition()`

Comment: Yeah, I finally got what he wanted :) @ClémentAndraud take a look at my code, and see if it helps :)